# Extract Column Value Out Of Spark "Column" Data Type Variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am passing in columns to a function in Spark (Scala). Each column is guaranteed to have as single row.

```
val testCol = lit("ColumnValue").as("ColumnName")
String result = testCol.toString()
```

I'm getting back the value of the result variable as the literal string `res696: String = ColumnValue AS 'ColumnName'`. Is there a way to get only the value of a Spark Column object via `toString()` or a different method? Such that I would get back `ColumnValue` alone.

An example of expanded context related to my usage.

```
someDataFrame.select($"SomeColumn", 
                     doLogic($"SomeDateColumnName", $"SomeStringColumnName").as("ComputedColumn"))
```

Where `doSomeLogic` needs to

```
def doSomeLogic(col1 : Column, col2 : Column) : Column = { 
     val col1Str = col1.toString() 
     val col2Str = col2.toString()
        
  // Do some logic. Take the strings and convert them to other types, do some comparisons
  // and eventually return a lit(SomeValue) to be plugged into the select. 
}
```

Comment: you can use withColumn to add the new column and in withColumn you can pass the function to set the value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

I am just assuming that you want the column value that you are assigning with literal you can easily do that using withColumn.

Simple example as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val testCol = lit("ColumnValue")
//Output = ColumnValue
val df = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF()
val df1 = df.withColumn("Test",testCol)
display(df1)
```

Output is as below :

[image]